# how to handle roles in an organization

Tags: opportunitycontactrole, opportunity-teams

I received following requirement but not able to compile how to do this. where should i start from and which path should i follow to fulfill the following requirements.

> 1) I need to create a new "XXXX" Role in the application for the
>   opportunity users and give this role to "edit permissions" to
>   opportunity.
>
> 2) Opportunity owner should only have right to assign this role to an
>   user.
>
> 3) Assignment of role "XXXX" should also be allowed at profile level.

If anyone can give pointers it would be great help for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're describing is Opportunity Sales Teams, which is different from Roles. This allows defining a specific group of users as part of the Opportunity Team. The Owner can control what level of access Team Members have.

Here is an overview: [Opportunity Teams](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=salesteam_def.htm&language=en_US). You just need to Enable Team Selling to get started.

Answer (score 2):

Roles expand user permissions to access to records beyond what their profile would normally allow. Generally speaking, Salesforce makes security as restrictive as possible using profiles, then uses roles, sharing rules and permission sets to expand access to objects according to the needs of an organization. Profiles and Roles aren't something I can succinctly explain in a message here to the extent you're asking about. There's an excellent explanation and tutorials on how to use and configure them in the [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) which should profide you with the kind of examples and explanation of what you need to know in order to accomplish what you've described above.